# Class cast exception while setting name

Tags: java

I am getting a cast exception while setting the name.

```
        Object[] customers= customerRepository.getCustomerName(Id);     
        Customer row = new Customer();          
        row.setName((String) customers[0]+" "+(String) customers[1]);
```

The exception is:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: 
[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Comment: I tried row.setName( customers[0].toString() ); But it won't give me the name.

Comment: are you certain `students[0]` is a string and not a complex object? What does the method `getCustomerName` look like?

Comment: @scrappedcola  @Query("select s.user.firstName, s.user.lastName from Customer s where s.id = ?1")
Object[] getCustomerName(Long cusId);

Comment: But two -1 votes for asking the same question twice.

Answer (score 1):

What you're getting above is:

```
  row.setName(((String) customers)[0]+" "+((String) customers)[1]);
```

Cast has precedence over array indexing.

The clue is the message `[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

The leading `[` indicates that the class is an array class.